# How to find the number of days between two dates in Groovy, removing government holidays?

Tags: date, groovy

We need to find the number of days between two dates in Groovy and remove US Government holidays.  Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116936/how-to-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-java-or-groovy), with a different wrinkle.

We were trying to brainstorm the best way to store the dates in Groovy as certain dates are fixed (New Years, 4th of July, Christmas) and other dates are flexible(President's Day is the third Monday in February).  Then check the dates if it contains any of the US Government Holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a domain class with the government holidays.

```
class GHolidays {
     Date date
     String description
}
```

After in controller create a method to obtain days between your two dates and remove the Government Holidays

```
class ExampleController {
     def daysGH = GHolidays.createCriteria().get{
          projections {
               count("id")
          } 
          between("date", date1, date2)
     }  

     use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
          def duration = date1 - date2
          def daysWithoutGH = duration.days - daysGH
          println "Days without Government holidays: ${daysWithoutGH}"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would do.

```
enum US2015holidays {
    New_Years_Day('01/01'),    
    Martin_Luther_King_Day('01/19'),
    Groundhog_Day('02/02', false),
    Presidents_Day('02/16'),
    Emancipation_Day('04/16', false),
    Mothers_Day('05/10'),
    Memorial_Day('05/25'),
    Fathers_Day('06/21', false),
    Independence_Day('07/03'),
    Labor_Day('09/07'),
    Columbus_Day('10/12'),
    Veterans_Day('11/11'),
    Thanksgiving('11/26'),
    Day_after_Thanksgiving('11/27'),
    Christmas_Day('12/25')

    private final Date holiday
    private final boolean isObserved

    US2015holidays(String day, boolean isObserved = true) {
        this.holiday = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', "2015/$day")
    }

    public Date getHoliday() {
        isObserved ? holiday : null
    }
}

import static java.util.Calendar.*

def noOfWorkingDays = 0
Date begin = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', '2015/01/01')
Date end   = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', '2015/04/11')

begin.upto( end ) {
    if ( !( it[DAY_OF_WEEK] in [ SUNDAY, SATURDAY ] || 
            it.clearTime()  in US2015holidays.values()*.holiday ) ) {
        noOfWorkingDays++
    }
}

println noOfWorkingDays
```

*Note:* Holidays might differ based on Geography. For example: *Good Friday* is observed here in Columbus, OH but I have not seen it being observed anywhere else.