# Number of days between 2 dates, groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have created a calculated field to get number of days between 2 dates.
I am using this formula:

```
<!-- @@Formula:
issue.get("customfield_10000")==null ? null : 
(issue.get("customfield_10000").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10001").getTime()) / (1000*3600*24)
-->
```

Please, can you help me, what syntax to use to dateparse the customfield datepicker ?

Comment: <!-- @@Formula:
issue.get("customfield_10000")==null ? null : 
(issue.get("customfield_10000").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10001").getTime()) / (1000*3600*24)
-->

Comment: is this jira?  you should add informations like this via tags.

Comment: Also, I assume this question isn't what the title says, or else you'd have tried a search and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116936/how-to-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-java-or-groovy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().parse(<format>,<time data>)` to create Date objects. Subtract two Date objects results in the difference in days.